# Why is a signing certificate needed for Implicit Flow in IdentityServer3, but not for ClientCredential and ResourceOwner flows?

Tags: certificate, implicit, signing, identityserver3

I'm trying to get up to speed on using IdentityServer3 for authorization in a .NET web application.

I'm trying to figure out why the Implicit Flow requires that IdentityServer have a signing certificate while the Authorization Flows do not require that.

So far, this is what I understand: the Flows "ClientCredential" and "ResourceOwner" are "AuthorizationFlows" - i.e. they have a client secret, all tokens are returned from the token endpoint, long-lived authentication via refresh tokens is possible, tokens are not revealed to the user agent/browser (rather, they are stored on the server, and a cookie or similar is sent to the user agent/browser) per https://www.scottbrady91.com/OpenID-Connect/OpenID-Connect-Flows. For a SPA / JS application that directly accesses a WebAPI, Implicit Flow should be used instead because the JS client calls the Identity Server directly from the browser, so there's no way for a client secret to be preserved (since it would have to be transmitted to the browser, thereby compromising the security).

All of that makes sense, but in all cases, the IdentityServer generates tokens that the application uses for authorization, so I'm puzzled why they need to be signed in one case but not in the other?

Many thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

A signing certificate is needed anytime a JWT is issued (id_token or access_token).

Comment: Thank you very much! I am still a bit confused as it's my understanding that all three flows allow the caller to obtain an access token... Is that token a JWT for the Implicit flow, and some other token type for the ClientCredentials and ResourceOwner flows? If so, why the different types of tokens for the different flows?